Почему не останавливается Wav звук в Java?
Я написал 2 класса на Java, которые выводят на экран кнопку с надписью "выкл." (выключено).
По моей задумке, если нажать на кнопку с надписью "выкл.", то начнёт проигрываться музыка, и на экране появится другая кнопка, но уже с надписью "вкл." (включено). Если нажать на кнопку с надписью "вкл.", то музыка должна остановится, но почему-то этого не происходит. Почему?
Первый класс:
package b;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
public class Main extends JFrame {
    public static JLabel turned_off = new JLabel();
    public static JLabel included = new JLabel();
    public static int incX=0,incY=0;
    public static int turnX=0,turnY=0;
    public static boolean is_inc;
    public static Music music;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        music = new Music("C:\\Users\\Петр\\IdeaProjects\\Flappy_Bull3_final\\src\\Flap\\music.wav",0.8);
        //display:
        Main display = new Main();
        display.setSize(300,325);
        GameField gameField = new GameField();
        display.add(gameField);
        display.setVisible(true);
        display.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //turned:
        turned_off.setFont(new Font("k",Font.ROMAN_BASELINE,20));
        turned_off.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(53,20));
        turned_off.setOpaque(true);
        turned_off.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        turned_off.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        turned_off.setSize(85,20);
        turned_off.setText("выкл.");
        //included:
        included.setFont(new Font("k",Font.ROMAN_BASELINE,20));
        included.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(37,20));
        included.setOpaque(false);
        included.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        included.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        included.setSize(85,20);
        included.setText("");
        //add:
        gameField.add(turned_off);
        gameField.add(included);
        gameField.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                int tX = e.getX();
                int tY = e.getY();
                float turn_x_r = turnX + turned_off.getWidth();
                float turn_y_d = turnY + turned_off.getHeight();
                boolean is_turn = tX >= turnX && tX <= turn_x_r && tY >= turnY && tY <= turn_y_d;
                if(is_turn){
                    music.play();
                    music.setVolume();
                    turned_off.setOpaque(false);
                    turned_off.setText("");
                    included.setText("вкл.");
                    included.setOpaque(true);
                    gameField.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                            int iX = e.getX();
                            int iY = e.getY();
                            float inc_x_r = incX + included.getWidth();
                            float inc_y_d = incY + included.getHeight();
                            is_inc = iX >= incX && iX <= inc_x_r && iY >= incY && iY <= inc_y_d;
                            if(is_inc){
                                System.out.println("kkk");
                                music.stop();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private static class GameField extends JPanel{
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            included.setLocation(incX,incY);
            turned_off.setLocation(turnX,turnY);
            super.paintComponent(g);
            repaint();
        }
    }
}

Второй класс:
package b;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Music {
    private final String path;
    private double vl;
    private FloatControl volume = null;
    public static Clip clip = null;
    public Music(String path, double vl){
        this.path=path;
        this.vl=vl;
    }
    public void play(){
        File AudioFile = new File(this.path);
        AudioInputStream ais = null;
        try{
            ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioFile);
        }catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(ais);
            volume = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
            clip.setFramePosition(0);
            clip.start();
        }catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void setVolume(){
        if(vl<0)vl=0;
        if(vl>1)vl=1;
        float min = volume.getMinimum();
        float max = volume.getMaximum();
        volume.setValue((max-min)*(float) vl+min);
    }
    public void stop(){
        clip.stop();
        clip.close();
    }
}


В чём ошибка? Как ее воспроизвести?

Неправильно работаете с обработчиками событий.
Обработчики событий не заменяют друг друга, они выстраиваются в очередь и будут вызваны последовательно друг за другом. Если убрать пока логику звука и написать  следующее:
gameField.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("start fired");
        gameField.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("stop fired");        
            }
        });
        System.out.println("---");
    }
}

То получите следующую картину:
start fired
---
start fired
stop fired
---
start fired
stop fired
stop fired
---
start fired
stop fired
stop fired
stop fired
---
start fired
stop fired
stop fired
stop fired
stop fired

Итого сначала запускается первый раз мелодия. Потом запускается мелодия еще раз, ссылки перетираются, тут же останавливается - ссылки затерлись, первая продолжает играть. Далее все повторяется, создается мелодия, останавливается несколько раз, но самая первая продолжает играть.
Итого
Вам надо разобраться в порядках вызовов событий и как они работают, чтобы не плодить кучу вызовов и объектов. Ваш код менять сильно не буду, просто покажу, как можно было бы реализовать это так, чтобы работало.
public class Main extends JFrame {
    ... 
    // Вводим флаг, чтобы понимать проигрывается мелодия или нет
    public static boolean isStarted; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
        // Одно событие, ориентируемся на флаг, надо остановить или воспроизвести
        gameField.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                int mouseX = e.getX();
                int mouseY = e.getY();

                float turn_x_r = turnX + turned_off.getWidth();
                float turn_y_d = turnY + turned_off.getHeight();
                float inc_x_r = incX + included.getWidth();
                float inc_y_d = incY + included.getHeight();

                boolean is_turn = mouseX >= turnX && mouseX <= turn_x_r && mouseY >= turnY && mouseY <= turn_y_d;
                boolean is_inc = mouseX >= incX && mouseX <= inc_x_r && mouseY >= incY && mouseY <= inc_y_d;

                if (!isStarted && is_turn) {
                    music.play();
                    music.setVolume();
                    turned_off.setOpaque(false);
                    turned_off.setText("");
                    included.setText("вкл.");
                    included.setOpaque(true);
                } else if (isStarted && is_inc) {
                    music.stop();
                }
                isStarted = !isStarted;
            }
        });

        ...
    }
    ...
}



    

